# Unable to fetch a word containing spaces using to_tsvector and to_tsquery

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I want to fetch a word entered by a user in the database:

```
select name 
from users
where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery('$word:*')
```

I mention `word = alain john smith`, when I run the query  I got this error:

```
syntax error in tsquery: "alain john smith"
```

The `plainto_tsquery`  cannot recognize Boolean operators, weight labels, or prefix-match labels in its input [Parsing queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch-controls.html)

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `tsquery` cannot contain `alain john smith`, since the parser will split this into three words.

If you have PostgreSQL 9.6 or later, you can use

```
to_tsquery('alain <-> john <-> smith')
```

which makes use of the “followed by” operator `<->`.

In older versions, the best you can do is

```
to_tsquery('alain & john & smith')
```

which will match strings containing all three words, but not necessarily adjacent or in this order.